# Access VBA Moving from one listbox to another

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I have a listbox named lstAvailable and i am moving the item selcted from this to another listbox named lstAssigned and also the value that gets sent here is stored in the table tblComponents. The values are storing in the table but i am not able to see the moved item in the listbox lstAssigned. Can someone help me?

The Code is

```
nRid = listMachineSubSystem.Column(1)
For Each varRow In lstAvailable.ItemsSelected
nEid = lstAvailable.Column(0, varRow)
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblComponents ([Machine Subsystem ID], [NewComponents])" _
    & " VALUES (" & nRid & ", " & nEid & ");"

    CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
    Next varRow
    lstAvailable.Requery
    lstAssigned.Requery
    For Each varItem In lstAvailable.ItemsSelected
        lstAvailable.Selected(varItem) = False
    Next
    For Each varItem In lstAssigned.ItemsSelected
        lstAssigned.Selected(varItem) = False
    Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: What is the rowsource for lstAssigned? Because that is what will be refreshed when you perform a requery. Furthermore, you should perform the requery's only at the end, not after every insert.

Comment: yeah i had not added the row source, I have one more probrlem that is , i want to add two more column data from the listbox to the table , but both are text values and when i add it to the above it gives an eror